# Fragment doesn't show up when using Navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm trying to build an application based on Fragments and the Navigation component. The sample code below is what I belief to be the absolute minimum.

My activity's layout looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The corresponding activity class looks like the following. Note that as of yet I'm not using any toolbar, nor bottom navigation, nor a menu.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The start fragment to display is just a ConstraintLayout defining some regular buttons and a floating action button.

The fragment's implementation looks like this:

```java
public class FragmentMainScreen extends Fragment
{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen, container, false);
    }
}
```

Lastly, the navigation graph is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/destination_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/destination_main"
        android:name="com.stmoebius.zz.ui.FragmentMainScreen"
        android:label="@string/main_screen_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_screen" />
</navigation>
```

Everything builds and executes just fine, but the fragment doesn't show up (except for its label). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave fragment width and height as 0dp

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</FrameLayout>
```